# How to refresh all views in Panels with a time interval without page refresh?

Tags: views, panels

I have some views that I want to refresh in a time interval (15sec) OR if there is changes in the content. For that I tried to use module "Views Auto Refresh". It works fine for a time interval but only if I have one view in a page.

If I have multiple views inside a panel (using Panels module), only one of the views is refreshed.

Is there any other way (module or custom code) to achieve this behaviour?

Thanks!

EDIT: As suggested, I tracked the ajax requests. In my case I'm refreshing every 15seconds. In a panel with 2 views I notice that I have only one request every 15sec, should I have two?!?!? Anyway, below is the piece of code I get when clicking in the function in red in the picture (I think is this one). The debug highlights the following line:

```
$(anchor).trigger('click');
```

[image: Ajax Requset]

```
Drupal.views_autorefresh.timer = function(view_name, anchor, target) {
  Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].timer = setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].timer);

    // Turn off "new" items class.
    $('.views-autorefresh-new', target).removeClass('views-autorefresh-new');

    // Handle ping path.
    var ping_base_path;
    if (Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].ping) {
      ping_base_path = Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].ping.ping_base_path;
    }

    // Handle secondary view for incremental refresh.
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object
    var viewData = Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].ajax.submit;
    var viewArgs = Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].view_args;
    if (Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].incremental) {
      if (!viewData.original_view_data) viewData.original_view_data = $.extend(true, {}, viewData);
      viewData.view_args = viewArgs + (viewArgs.length ? '/' : '') + Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].timestamp;
      viewData.view_base_path = Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].incremental.view_base_path;
      viewData.view_display_id = Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].incremental.view_display_id;
      viewData.view_name = Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].incremental.view_name;
    }
    viewData.autorefreshRequest = 'autorefreshRequest';
    Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].ajax.submit = viewData;

    // If there's a ping URL, hit it first.
    if (ping_base_path) {
      var pingData = { 'timestamp': Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].timestamp };
      $.extend(pingData, Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].ping.ping_args);
      $.ajax({
        url: Drupal.settings.basePath + ping_base_path,
        data: pingData,
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.pong && parseInt(response.pong) > 0) {
            $(target).trigger('autorefresh_ping', parseInt(response.pong));
            $(anchor).trigger('click');
          }
          else {
            Drupal.views_autorefresh.timer(view_name, anchor, target);
          }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {},
        dataType: 'json',
      });
    }
    else {
      $(anchor).trigger('click');
    }
  }, Drupal.settings.views_autorefresh[view_name].interval);
}
```

Comment: You should track the ajax requests to see what parameters sent, after that you may check the module source code and api to find how achieve your scenario BTW I know the module developer personally so He could help

Comment: Thanks Mhmdgomma. I edited my question with the ajax request. That help would be awesome!

Comment: The problem is that I'm not using two different views in the same page. I'm using same view, different displays and this module only takes into account view name.

Comment: You are welcomed and I am very happy that your problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Views Auto-Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh) module with this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/node/2143727#comment-8212611)

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in the past with the help of [Views Auto-Refresh](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autorefresh)

Try the module and let us know if it work.

Comment: Hi Yama, I have that module installed as I said in my question. The problem is that it doesn't update all views if they are inside a panel.